# Infragistics WebDataGrid column layout not maintained on Insert and Delete

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I've come across this weird issue with the Infragistics WebDataGrid control.

When the grid starts, it appears ok, headers on the header row. There are no entries, so the only row displayed below is the "add" row.

[image]

I then load data into the grid from my AJAX code-behind. It appears ok. The 3 new rows appear, the "add" row sits below. Everything clean.

[image]

I then click the delete "x" in the 2nd row (sidenote: this is a template column and is the first column in the grid, so why it appears at the end I do not know). The AJAX kicks in and the 2nd row is removed. But the grid refreshes odd. It looks like a new column has appeared on the "add" row, which has thrown the other rows and header out.

[image]

It is functionally correct, but visually a mess.

NOTE: This also happens when you add a new entry from the "add" row.

FYI - I have followed pieces of Craig Shoemaker's example, however I bind my datasource in the code-behind, amongst other changes. (http://community.infragistics.com/aspnet/articles/webdatagrid-client-side-crud.aspx).

Anyone know what causes this / how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

I tested this and I wasn't able to reproduce this.  I would recommend that if you can still reproduce this you post the issue on the Infragistics [forums](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/196.aspx) with the code that you are using so that we can look into it further.